# having trouble with design in codeigniter project, using inheritance

Tags: php, codeigniter, inheritance

Iam currently reworking my project in codeigniter to set it up so that I have a User.php superclass. this class then has 2 subclasses "carer_user" and "admin_user" whenn logging i have a method called login in the super class whos index is called first. after this i will decide which user type has is being logged in and display the relevant page for that specific user type. each is different. how i have it set up currently seems wrong to me as i have the login in the superclass User. for each user type is set up slightly differently,runs different querys agains the db, creates session differently. also i dont think its proper practice to call a subclass method from a super class one the login has been verified. my question(s) is/are this. should login be in a controller class of its own? once verification has been done here i can then call a method in either admin_user or carer_user depending on the result.or should i stick with the way iam doing it right now, my code is shown below for my User controller method. thanks!

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

    var $loggedin = FALSE;
    var $cdata;
    var $privilege;

    function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model("dbaccess");

        $this->cdata =array( "warning" => "","email"=> "","password"=> "","logintime"=>"","start"=>"","end"=>""
        ,"diff"=>"","totalhours"=>"","dis"=>$this); 

    }


public function index()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('email'))
    {
        $this->load->view('carerview',$this->cdata);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('mainview',$this->cdata);
    }

}



public function login()
{

       if(isset($_POST['email'])  && isset($_POST['password']))
       {
         $this->cdata['email'] = $_POST['email'] ;
         $this->cdata['password'] = $_POST['password'] ;
        }

        if($this->cdata['email'] !=="" && $this->cdata['password'] !=="" && $this->loggedin === FALSE)
        {

            $this->loggedin = $this->dbaccess->check_input($this->cdata['email'],$this->cdata['password']);
            if($this->loggedin)
            {
                $data =array("email"=>$this->cdata['email']);
                $this->privilege = $this->dbaccess->get_privilege($data,"userinfo");
                $this->open_page();
                $this->loggedin= TRUE;

            }
            else
            {
                $this->cdata['warning']="Check failed ! Please try again";
                $this->load->view('mainview',$this->cdata);
            }


        }
        else if($this->loggedin ===TRUE)
        {
            //check helpermethod. go to relevant page.
            $this->open_page();
        }
       else
       {
            $this->cdata['warning']="Check failed ! Please try again";
            $this->load->view('mainview',$this->cdata);
        }
}

private function open_page()
{
    switch($this->privilege)
    {
        case 0 :
        $this->carerview();
        break;
        case 1:
        $this->admin();
        break;


    }
}
}

?>
```

again my problem with this is where the login method should be placed? and the fact that i cant really have a superclass calling a method in one of its subclasses.

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not possible. You either can use interfaces

Comment: again, this is not multiple inheritance. unless ive lost my mind. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple inheritance is not possible. You either can use interfaces.
Please have a look here for better explanation https://github.com/sepehr/ci-base-controllers

Comment: this is just regular inheritance as there is only one superclass!?

Comment: okay i think ill just setup a library, that the login controller can use to create the different type of seesions and send data to the database in the case of the 'carer_user'.

Comment: wow no ones helped me out with this, not being able to call a controllerfrom another one is a bit of a problem for me. iam going going to try using hmvc